# Resultados con paginación

Tags: php, mysql, paginación

Cómo puedo hacer para que en este buscador me pagine los resultados, ya que tengo una base de datos con muchos datos y necesito que los resultados de la búsqueda salgan por páginas. ¿cómo puedo agregarle un paginador a este código?

Adjunto código del formulario y php. Gracias por su ayuda.

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Curso</label>
      <input required name="PalabraClave" type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Ingrese palabra clave">  
      <input name="buscar" type="hidden" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" value="v">
    </div>
   
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Buscar Ahora</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
  </li>

</ul>
```

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['PalabraClave']);
    $query ="SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE lenguaje like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%' OR descripcion like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'";
    for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
        if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
            $query .= " OR descripcion like '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%'";
        }
    }
    $result = $db->query($query);
    echo "<br>Has buscado la palabra clave:<b> ". $_POST['PalabraClave']."</b>";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row_count=0;
        echo "<br><br>Resultados encontrados: ";
        echo "<br><table class='table table-striped'>";
        While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
            $row_count++;                         
            echo "<tr><td>".$row_count." </td><td>". $row['lenguaje'] . "</td><td>". $row['descripcion'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Resultados encontrados: Ninguno";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: y ese código que hace??

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta de SOes de como implementar una paginación PHP, quizas te puede servir, así puedes investigar y hacer pruebas con tu código, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/como-cambiar-entre-listas-o-paginas-de-registros-con-botones-de-siguiente-o-ant/46669#46669

Comment: Hola, necesito es que me pagine el resultado de la búsqueda, que cuando alguien busque algo en la web, los resultados se paginen y no me salga la lista larga de resultados.